# Does check_symbol_exists work on network drives? Or have some other similar limitation?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake file that works everywhere I've tried it except on a virtual machine.

I tried making a minimal example:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS( "A" "C:/Users/user/Downloads/test.h" X)
MESSAGE( STATUS "X: ${X}" )
```

Which outputs "X:".

Where C:/Users/user/Downloads/test.h contains

```
#define A
```

The only thing I can think of is the fact that the virtual machine is using some sort of network drive where the paths aren't the real paths?  If there is not a known reason why that wouldn't work is there a verbose mode or some better way to debug this?

The installed version of CMake is 3.18.1, unfortunately I don't have a way to update to the newest version.

Comment: Consult CMake log to see why this check fails.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It was throwing an error, and I believe it was because the network share paths started with '//', moving it to a drive with a proper name worked.